# String contains letters

Tags: ios, methods, nsstring

I'm wondering if there is a way to check if a string is containing a letter.

If there is an `NSString = @"street 12"` I want it to return `YES`
and if `NSString = @"12.12,23.23"` I want it to return `NO`

Is there a method that handles this made by Apple or do I have to make it myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
NSString *someString = ... // the string to check
NSRange match = [someString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, someString.length)];
if (match.location != NSNotFound) {
    // someString has a letter in it
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind you can create your own characterSet from the characters you want to allow.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"];

if ([str rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) {
    return YES;
}

return NO;
```

Comment: This may or may not fit the needs of the OP. There are far more "letters" than A-Z and a-z. There are accented letters and letters from other alphabets.

Comment: Of course. This is only correct under the assumption of standard english characters. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @Arbitur Don't forget to consider your international user base. Depending on the strings you are checking, the values could have letters in Greek, Russian, Japanese, etc. It may not be appropriate to focus just on A-Z.

Comment: I totally agree with @rmaddy. If it suits your needs, it's great but take in account the limitations of this implementation.

Comment: In my case This would wotk fine because it's only going to be used in Sweden, and of course I add the åäö in the NSCharacterSer ;) but the code would look a little bit ugly, sorry :S