# Validate in a simple method a username on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, textview

I need to validate the username that people use when loggin in my app. For example:

Peter$@ is not valid but
peter123 is valid

If the username includes a .!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~@,; on his name, an alertView should appear to inform the user

Do I have to compare strings like this?

```
-(BOOL) checkIfUsernameValidation{
    NSString *_username = playerName.text;
    NSString *expression = @".!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~@,;";

    if(![_username compare:expression]){
        return YES;
    }
    else
        return NO;
}
```

thanks

Comment: maybe this thread will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866879/string-contains-letters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a [NSCharacterSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

For example, create a character set of all the characters you'll allow, and then look at your text field and use something like this:

```
NSCharacterSet * characterSetFromTextField = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: yourTextField];
if([[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] isSupersetOfSet: characterSetFromTextField] == NO)
{
    NSLog( @"there are bogus characters here, throw up a UIAlert at this point");
    return;
}
```

I used alphanumericCharacterSet, but you can just as easily create your own character set of all your allowed characters using ["`characterSetWithCharactersInString`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/characterSetWithCharactersInString%3a).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a `UITextField`, you can act as the delegate and implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` and then use `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:` with a character set created from your string of not-allowed characters. If a valid range is found then you can show the alert as soon as the user has typed an invalid character.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL) checkIfUsernameValidation{
    NSString *_username = playerName.text;

    NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@".!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~@,;"] invertedSet];

    if ([_username rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound){
        return YES;
    }
    else
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)isValidUsername {
  NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet
      characterSetWithCharactersInString:@".!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~@,;"];

  return [self rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location == NSNotFound;
}
```